# Problem of extremely varied reward value in DDQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, q-learning, dqn

I am trying to train my model by DDQN agent after creating a customized environment in gym. I am stating my hyper-parameters and other details here.

```
state shape = 5

action space = 0,1,2, ..., 100

episode length = 1669

episodes = 300

Neural-Net shape = (5, 25, 50, 101)

target_model_update=1e-2,

gamma= 0.99

Batch size = 128

learning rate = 1e-3

warmup steps = 1500

Linear Annealed Policy with number of steps=1669*290, minimum epsilon = 0.001, maximum epsilon = 1

Replay Buffer limit = 1669*30

target_model_update = 1e-2
```

The total reward of each episode wrt the episode number while training can be shown in the following picture[image]

If I change the learning rate from 1e-3 to 1e-4 then I get [image]

Reducing the learning has increased the maximum reward value while training. However, both learning rates still result in high fluctuation in the total reward. It seems like the reward is very sensitive to the actions performed by the DDQN agent. The fluctuation in reward is much bigger than the start of the training.

This is counter-intuitive to me since the exploration rate decreases as the step number increases. Lower exploration should result in a lower variance in the reward value. Even though the average reward does flatten out, in both cases the reward variance is much higher at the end than at the beginning of the training.

The Four values out of the five values of state is not dependent on the previous action made by the agent. So it makes the convergence of the algorithm very hard. I have tried tuning hyper parameters, but could not achieve better than the above two cases.

Kindly help me to understand why there is such high variance in reward as the training steps increase and recommend possible solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Subhajit Saha, and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! Interesting question! If possible, could you please state the specifics of your environment? Thanks, and we look forward to more of your questions in the future!

Comment: Without further algo details information, maybe you're just entering the deadly triad zone.